# Trouble with ITextSharp - Converting XML to PDF

Tags: c#, xml, pdf-generation, itext

Okay... I'm trying to use the most recent version of ITextSharp to turn an XML file into a PDF.  It isn't working.

The documentation on SourceForge doesn't seem to have kept up with the actual releases; the code in the provided example won't even compile under the newest version.

Here is my test XML:

```
<Remittance>
<RemitHeader>
<Payer>BlueCross</Payer>
<Provider>Maricopa</Provider>
<CheckDate>20100329</CheckDate>
<CheckNumber>123456789</CheckNumber>
</RemitHeader>
<RemitDetail>
<NPI>NPI_GOES_HERE</NPI>
<Patient>Patient Name</Patient>
<PCN>0034567</PCN>
<DateOfService>20100315</DateOfService>
<TotalCharge>125.57</TotalCharge>
<TotalPaid>55.75</TotalPaid>
<PatientShare>35</PatientShare>
</RemitDetail>
</Remittance>
```

And here is the code I'm attempting to use to turn that into a PDF.

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 36, 36, 36, 36);
  iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, 
    new StreamWriter(fileOutputPath).BaseStream);
  doc.Open();
  SimpleXMLParser.Parse((ISimpleXMLDocHandler)doc, 
    new StreamReader(fileInputPath).BaseStream);
  doc.Close();
```

Now, I was pretty sure the `(ISimpleXMLDocHandler)doc` piece wasn't going to work, but I can't actually find anything in the source that both a) implements ISimleXMLDocHandler and b) will accept a standard XML document and parse it to PDF.

FYI- I did try an older version which would compile using the example code from sourceforge, but it wasn't working either.

Comment: I remember running across something that indicated they separated the non-PDF features (HTML and RTF for sure) into a separate dll.  Maybe they pulled the XML features into that separate dll as well?

Comment: @John Fisher- I don't think so (I could certainly be wrong) but I'm not finding anything in any of the other namespaces; and there's only one .dll available...

Comment: Maybe I misremembered and it was simply a namespace change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After browsing the 5.0.2 code, it looks like there is no document that will just take XML and turn it into a PDF for you.  So, unless you can find similar code on the web or in an old release of iTextSharp, you'll need to write it yourself.

Comment: It looks like you're right.  I guess I'll just write it myself.

Answer (score 0):

iText XML to PDF requires that the XML be formatted according to itext.dtd (please Google responsibly).  You can also use a tagmap.xml to map your XML entities to those appropriate according to the DTD.